# How to run UI tests in Visual Studio with PhantomJs, QUnit and Chutzpah?

Tags: visual-studio, phantomjs, resharper, qunit, chutzpah

I have successfully run QUnit UI tests from command line via PhantomJs and open source script run-qunit.js, see screen below:
[image]
There are simple tests which checks that html elements(input, ahref, span) were loaded. 
But I could not run this test from Visual Studio. I have tried all kinds of paths in 'Command line arguments', see screenshot:
[image]

But when I run test I receive:
[image]

So, the main idea is to **run ui-test from Visual Studio**, not from cmd.

FYI:
Resharper, PhantomJs, Chutzpah, QUnit were added to VS 2015.